# update statement not effective

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
.
.
.
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");
$query="UPDATE table SET a='$A', b='$B', c='$C', WHERE id='$ID'";

$checkresult = mysql_query($query);
if ($checkresult) {
echo "Success";
} else {
echo "Sorry, it failed !";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

The script will edit and replace the field with new information gained by input.

It will echo `Success` as expected, but the row hasn't changed.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: where does the $ID variable coming from? are you sure it's a valid ID?

Comment: @aporat Yes it is good, it comes from another form : $id=mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");

Comment: Print out your query just do echo $query; If it still looks good to you with all the variables correct, run the printed query in phpMyadmin.

Comment: Aww it gives me : UPDATE vbots SET a='', b='',c='', WHERE id=''Success

Comment: OK Thank you , all fixed. I was stupid and forgot to save the data on variables .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
$query="UPDATE table SET a='$A', b='$B', c='$C', WHERE id='$ID'";
```

with this:

```
$query="UPDATE table SET a='{$A}', b='{$B}', c='{$C}' WHERE id='{$ID}'";
```

Comment: add you might want to escape the variables before inserting them into the database, using the mysql_real_escape_string() function

Comment: change: `mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);` with: `$conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');` and this: `mysql_query($query)` with this: `mysql_query($query, $conn)`

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a comma before the "where". But I would think that would give you a syntax error, not get a bogus success return.

Comment: without it is same. I can't find any explication why this doesn't work. Shall i post the from from wich comes the data?